# Placeholder/Error/Fallback in Glide v4

Tags: android, placeholder, android-glide

i am using latest version of Glide as of now which is **glide:4.0.0-RC1** and not able to find methods like placeholder, error, fallback e.t.c. Probably they have provided alternate for it but i am not getting it. Anybody know about there alternatives in this release?

Comment: Read documentation of Glide. There might be given a description.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try this

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
requestOptions.error(R.drawable.error_img);

Glide.with(this)
                .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
                .load("")
                .into(imageViewPlaceholder);
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout migration details from [here](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html#requestoptions). Looks like they had lot more improvements.

You have new class **RequestOptions**:

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.error)
    .priority(Priority.HIGH);
```

Then,

```
Glide.with(fragment/activity)
    .load(url)
    .apply(options)
    .into(imageView);
```

To learn more about Migration Details, you can go [here](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html).