# Glide-4.0.0 Missing placeholder, error, GlideApp and does not resolve its method placeholder,error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-glide

I want to use the Glide Android library to download an image and show in `ImageView`.

In the previous version we used:

```
Glide.with(mContext).load(imgUrl)
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.PLACEHOLDER_IMAGE_NAME)
                .error(R.drawable.ERROR_IMAGE_NAME)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imageView);
```

But I have seen Glide documentation:

> it says use `GlideApp.with()` instead `Glide.with()`

My concern is a missing placeholder, error, GlideApp, and other options.

I am using

```
 compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
```

Where am I doing wrong? With reference to [here](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html).

How has `GlideApp.with()` been used?

The API is generated in the same package as the `AppGlideModule` and is named `GlideApp` by default. Applications can use the API by starting all loads with `GlideApp.with()` instead of `Glide.with()`:

```
GlideApp.with(fragment)
   .load(myUrl)
   .placeholder(placeholder)
   .fitCenter()
   .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Placeholder/Error/Fallback in Glide v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45187661/placeholder-error-fallback-in-glide-v4)

Comment: Do you have idea about GlideApp? how to use and when to use?..if not please upvote

Comment: you are missing step2 check this : http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/generatedapi.html

Comment: Follow this documentation bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/getting-started.html#applicatio‌​ns

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Try using **[RequestOptions](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html#requestoptions)**:

```
RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder);
requestOptions.error(R.drawable.ic_error);

Glide.with(context)
     .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)
     .load(url).into(holder.imageView);
```

**EDIT**

If `.setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions)` does not work, use `.apply(requestOptions)`:

```
Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(url)
            .apply(requestOptions)
            .into(imageview);
 // or this
 Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(url)
            .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.booked_circle).error(R.drawable.booked_circle))
            .into(imageview);

 // or this
 Glide.with(MainActivity.this)
            .load(url)
            .apply(RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.drawable.booked_circle).error(R.drawable.))
            .into(imageview);
```

**EDIT 2 Bonus**

Here are some other changes in Glide-4

- How to use [**`requestOptions.circleCropTransform();`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49399459/glid4-bitmapimageviewtarget-at-into-method/49399683#49399683)
- How to use [**`Cross fades()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174277/glide-withcontext-loadfile-bitmaplist-getposition-showing-error/50174551#50174551)
- How to use [**`GlideDrawableImageViewTarget`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51531229/glidedrawableimageviewtarget-not-found-in-glide-4/51531284#51531284)  in Glide-4
- How to use [**`GifDrawable`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52291674/glide-does-not-accepting-gifdrawable-as-target-parameter/52291959#52291959) as target parameter

Comment: that i also don't know @RiteshBhavsar its working in my device with new Glide lib you can check it

Comment: @NileshRathod RequestOptions should be used in builder style:

```RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.ic_placeholder).requestOptions.error(R.drawable.ic_error);```

Comment: This is a workaround without GlideApp. See https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1945 to learn how to add GlideApp.

Comment: is there any way to get Bitmap output like that Bitmap bitmap=Glide output

Comment: ic_placeholder is on red, compiler cant see it

Comment: @fluffykitten you need to provide drawable resource id instead of `ic_placeholder` which you need to use as a place holder

Answer (score 34):

If you use Glide package dependencies, `compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'`, then use should be to use the below code:

```
GlideApp
    .with(your context)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image)
    .error(R.drawable.error_image)
    .into(myImageView);
```

> **Note:** As in [the documentation](https://github.com/bumptech/glide),
>
> Round Pictures: CircleImageView/CircularImageView/RoundedImageView are
>   known to have issues with TransitionDrawable (.crossFade() with
>   .thumbnail() or .placeholder()) and animated GIFs, use a
>   BitmapTransformation (.circleCrop() will be available in v4) or
>   .dontAnimate() to fix the issue.

The latest updated version `compile com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1` then use should be to use the below code:

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
                    .centerCrop()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.default_avatar)
                    .error(R.drawable.default_avatar)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .priority(Priority.HIGH)
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .dontTransform();

Glide.with(this)
     .load(url)
     .apply(options)
     .into(imageView);
```

See the latest version of **[glide, bug fixes and features](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases)**.

Comment: glide is such weird library to use they haven't updated on github

Comment: Ya @AnandSavjani they didn't  updated in GitHub but you can find their updates into this link
https://github.com/bumptech/glide/releases

Comment: If you don't like glide then you can create your own way to load images ,gif that provide also Caching  and you can freely upload it into github and do always updated

Answer (score 11):

If you want to use GlideApp you have to add to `dependencies` annotation processor like on the screenshot:

[image: How to add GlideApp to your project]

Then include an AppGlideModule implementation in your application:

```
@GlideModule
public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {}
```

Do not forget about the `@GlideModule` annotation.
Then you need to Build project. And `GlideApp` will be automatically generated.

Comment: It was not working after sync gradle. But we need to do rebuild in order to make it work.

Answer (score 7):

We have no need to use RequestOptions also.

The generated API adds a GlideApp class, that provides access to RequestBuilder and RequestOptions subclasses. The RequestOptions subclass contains all methods in RequestOptions and any methods defined in GlideExtensions. The RequestBuilder subclass provides access to all methods in the generated RequestOptions subclass without having to use apply:

**Using Glide** :-

A request without the generated API might look like this:

```
Glide.with(fragment)
    .load(url)
    .apply(centerCropTransform()
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
        .error(R.drawable.error)
        .priority(Priority.HIGH))
    .into(imageView);
```

**Using GlideApp** :-

With the generated API, the `RequestOptions` calls can be inlined:

```
GlideApp.with(fragment)
    .load(url)
    .centerCrop()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
    .error(R.drawable.error)
    .priority(Priority.HIGH)
    .into(imageView);
```

You can still use the generated RequestOptions subclass to apply the same set of options to multiple loads, but generated RequestBuilder subclass may be more convenient in most cases.

Answer (score 6):

Dependencies:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.1.1'
```

Add an appropriately annotated AppGlideModule implementation:

```
import com.bumptech.glide.annotation.GlideModule;
import com.bumptech.glide.module.AppGlideModule;

@GlideModule
public final class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule{}
```

In addition, if you have used the jack option, in order to avoid the following similar errors, you need use Android Studio 3.0.0 preview.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.
>   com.android.jack.ir.JNodeInternalError: java.lang.Exception: java.lang.AssertionError: No yet implemented

Answer (score 4):

Working

```
Glide.with(context!!)
     .load(user.profileImage)
     .apply (RequestOptions.placeholderOf(R.drawable.dummy_user))
     .into(edit_profile_image)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a common placeholder everywhere in your app then you can do it like this way:

As we are creating **GlideModule** from **Glide v4**, you can copy/paste this class in your project so you will able to use **GlideApp** class (for more steps - [follow this)](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1939#issuecomment-442710301):

```
@GlideModule
public class SampleGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {
    @Override
    public void applyOptions(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull GlideBuilder builder) {
        super.applyOptions(context, builder);
        builder.setDefaultRequestOptions(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.logo).error(R.drawable.logo));
    }

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Glide glide, @NonNull Registry registry) {
        super.registerComponents(context, glide, registry);
    }
}
```

You can give all the request options here to set as **default**.

By creating this class you do not need to use `.placeholder` with `GlideApp`, it will be applied automatically.

Answer (score 1):

```
RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.null_image_profile)
            .error(R.drawable.null_image_profile);
    //.centerCrop()
    //.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    //.priority(Priority.HIGH);

    Glide.with(context).load(imageUrl)
            .apply(options)
            .into(profileImage);
```

Comment: Please add some explanation - a plain code block alone isn't all that informative