# Glide does not accepting GifDrawable as target parameter

Tags: android, android-glide

I'm trying to find out end of gif with glide.

this is the code that I find on web:

```
Glide.with(thisActivity).asGif().load(R.raw.logo_gif_motion_low).listener(object : RequestListener<GifDrawable> {
                override fun onLoadFailed(p0: GlideException?, p1: Any?, p2: Target<GifDrawable>, p3: Boolean): Boolean {

                }
                override  fun onResourceReady(p0: GifDrawable?, p1: Any?, p2: Target<GifDrawable>, p3: DataSource?, p4: Boolean): Boolean {

                    return false
                }
            }).into(splashscreen);
```

the problem is , it doesn't accept **GifDrawable** in **Target**.

the error saying that:

[image]

Comment: are you using GLide 3x or 4x ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082330/show-gif-file-with-glide-image-loading-and-caching-library

Comment: https://bumptech.github.io/glide/javadocs/380/com/bumptech/glide/load/resource/gif/GifDrawable.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
target: com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<GifDrawable>?
```

instead of

```
Target<GifDrawable>
```

Try this

```
    Glide.with(this).asGif().load("").listener(object : RequestListener<GifDrawable> {
        override fun onResourceReady(resource: GifDrawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<GifDrawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: com.bumptech.glide.request.target.Target<GifDrawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }


    }).into(splashscreen)
```

Comment: I get this compilation error:
`Type mismatch: inferred type is <no name provided> but RequestListener<GifDrawable!>? was expected`
Any idea?

Comment: How can we get the output in bitmap variable like Bitmap bitmap=Glide output and then add this bitmap to arraylist.

Answer (score 1):

In your build.gradle file  add following

Including Glide’s annotation processor requires dependencies on Glide’s annotations and the annotation processor:

```
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.8.0'
```

Add a dependency on Glide’s annotation processor:

```
repositories {
 mavenCentral()
 }

dependencies {
 annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Import the latest `Glide` dependencies to grade file.

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
```

Then use one of these solutions:

```
Glide.with(thisActivity)
        .asGif()
        .load(R.raw.logo_gif_motion_low)
        .listener(object : RequestListener<GifDrawable> {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: GifDrawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<GifDrawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                // TODO: Process your gif drawable here
                return false
            }

            override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<GifDrawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        }).into(splashscreen)
```

or

```
Glide.with(thisActivity)
        .load(R.raw.logo_gif_motion_low)
        .listener(object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
            override fun onResourceReady(resource: Drawable?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, dataSource: DataSource?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                val gifDrawable = resource as GifDrawable?
                gifDrawable?.let {
                    // TODO: Process your gif drawable here
                }
                return false
            }

            override fun onLoadFailed(e: GlideException?, model: Any?, target: Target<Drawable>?, isFirstResource: Boolean): Boolean {
                return false
            }
        })
        .into(splashscreen)
```